# What command should I be using to launch a program from the Lua Intepreter?

Tags: lua, prompt

I have been attempting to troubleshoot how to launch a program I write in Lua, and it seems to me that I should be launching the program from the Lua Interpreter. The First Edition of Programming in Lua tells me I should use the command `prompt> lua hello.lua`. The name of my program is "hello.lua" and it is in the same folder as the Interpreter but I get the error message '=' expected near '>'. What command should I be using? Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Under Windows (administrator console):

```
ftype Lua.File=C:\utils\lua.exe "%1" %*
```

(where c:\utils\lua.exe is the actual path of your Lua interpreter)

```
assoc .lua=Lua.File
```

Now, you can type: *hello.lua* directly at the command prompt

And, if in "Computer/Properties/Advanced/Environment Variables" (Win7 example) you add .LUA to the PATHEXT variable, you can simply type: *hello* at the command prompt, without the extension.

Comment: FWIW, my Lua distribution didn't have a `lua.exe` - the binary included the version number, ie `lua.5.x.exe`. I've created a symlink. Of course, simply adapting the file type registration would also work.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(I guess you are on some Unix or POSIX system)</sup>

Just type `lua hello.lua`; the `prompt>`  string is given by your shell (and the [prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt) is generally something different and configurable).

By typing literally `prompt>` you are asking your shell to run a program -or a command- named `prompt` and to [redirect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_%28computing%29) its [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) (to what follows the `>`)

Comment: An alternative (again assuming Unix/POSIX/Linux) is to add a line like `#!/usr/bin/lua` at the top of the source file; you can then run your script directly: `./hello.lua`.