# How do I run a Lua script?

Tags: windows, lua

I'm running on windows 10. I built lua, added it to my environment variables PATH but I cant figure out how to successfully run it.

I tried dragging a .lua file onto lua.exe but that just causes my explorer window to freeze up and crash. I tried calling lua or my particular lua file in the command prompt but it does nothing - no error, just sits there with no output. I've tried moving files around, using the command prompt while in the same directory as the lua.exe but nothing is working.

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCeZl.jpg)'s a picture of my command prompt. from tutorials and videos I've seen, simply executing lua like that should allow me to instantly start typing commands.

Comment: Just type `lua test.lua`.  Try to write single line `print"Hello world"` in `test.lua` to see it works.  And add `C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.3` to your `PATH` env variable to be able to invoke Lua from any folder.

Comment: Yes that's what I did and nothing happens. I just get a blinking cursor.

Comment: What does `lua.exe` say when started in console without arguments?  What "just sits there with no output" means?  Does it hangs?

Comment: How did you build Lua?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5D_h2X8LCk I followed this video using the visual studio command prompt and just copied those commands with 5.3 as the version number

Comment: What VS version did you use?  In case of troubles with building you can simply [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/luabinaries/files/5.3.2/Tools%20Executables/lua-5.3.2_Win32_bin.zip/download) Lua 5.3 binaries for Windows.

Comment: Yeah it hangs and control+c doesnt stop it

Comment: O.o so I downloaded that and it worked!! I put my original lua.exe back in and renamed it "lua53.exe" and it works now as well! Why does it need to be named lua53 rather than lua?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: Also have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34458941/what-command-should-i-be-using-to-launch-a-program-from-the-lua-intepreter/34470077#34470077

Answer (score 2):

Apparently renaming "Lua.exe" to "Lua53.exe" fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open the code editor terminal and type `lua filename.lua` and that should run the program in the file.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to run simple lua script to get the result, you can get "code runner" from chrome extension store. you can run lua on it.furthermore, you can share or load code with others with it.

Answer (score 0):

try using `dofile("directory of the lua file you want to call ex. lualib/lua.lua")` on your lua file. or if you want to run the script you can use [repl.it](https://repl.it)